# Howto mount and then unmount a filesystem in puppet?

Tags: puppet

I understand that in the same manifest, a resource type has a unique name.

For the "mount" resource, the name is the path where the device will be mounted.

I want to do the following with puppet :

1. mount an NFS partition
2. execute a script from this mount point
3. unmount this partition

So I declare :

> ```
> mount {'/mnt/tina':
>     device => 'tina-iuem:/distrib',
>     fstype => 'nfs',
>     options => "defaults",
>     remounts => false,
>     atboot => false,
>     ensure => mounted,
> }
> exec {'install':
>     command => '/mnt/tina/mycommand.sh'
> }
> ```

Then, how to unmount the '/mnt/tina' resource ?

Comment: Worth noting that a mount resource in puppet the name is indeed the path where the resource is mounted, however it only defaults to the title of the resource (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#mount-attribute-name).

You can name the resource whatever you want then define the name (mount point) inside the resource to where you need it to point, avoiding the duplicate resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately what you are attempting to do with puppet is not the intended "puppet way" so to speak.  Puppet is a configuration management tool not a tool designed for one time batch jobs, as such doing things like this become "annoying".

Given that you cannot have resources in conflict (aka mount ensure => mounted, and mount => absent) in the same catalog compile, you are probably better off offloading the mounting etc to a script and execcing out (Which sadly is in my opinion always the cheap way, but best suited for this situation.)

Comment: Thank you. You confirmed what I was suspecting.
I'll come out with a script for this task.